# Why am I able to go above the +200 daily reputation limit?

Tags: discussion, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

The FAQ clearly states that the reputation limit is 200, except for when an answer is accepted.

Why am I [getting reputation for upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/373496/josh-smith?tab=reputation) after I've hit the limit?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The +15 reputation you get for an accepted answer will *never* count towards the daily limit. From my quick-scan of your reputation thus far today, you're currently sitting at exactly 200 / 200 (because of the downvote) for the reputation cap. Any +15's you get for accepted answers are not considered in this calculation and are always added on.

**Your calculation:**

```
+10 x 18 =      180
+9 x 1   =        9
+5 x 1   =        5
+2 x 4   =        8
-2 x 1   =        2-
--------------------
                200
+15 x 6  =       90
--------------------
                290
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the insight! And for the added calculation details.

Answer (score 1):

> Why am I getting reputation for upvotes after I've hit the limit?

You aren't. Your 90 points' surplus comes from the six accepted answers you've had today.