# Not getting full credit for an answer

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why did I just lose 15 reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72207/why-did-i-just-lose-15-reputation)

Yesterday I had **1522** points I woke up this morning to find that I had an upvote and my answer was chosen as the right answer for this question

[Adding a class to Html.MenuItem's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734579/adding-a-class-to-html-menuitems/8734757#8734757)

my profile shows that I got **25 points**, but now my reputation is **1532**

I don't see any downvotes either!
and I am not at the 200 limit per day

This has happened before, so I figured I should ask maybe there is something I am missing.

**Where did my other 15 points go?**

Comment: 200 limit per day?

Comment: @TryTryAgain I have a vague understanding that there is a daily cap on reputation set to 200 a day, but one day I got >200 so I don't know if it's being enforced!

Comment: There are exceptions to the 200 rep/day limit, such as bounties.

Comment: @CodeWarrior yeah.. but that day I didn't get any bounty.. maybe it was because it was my first time to get >200 so they let it slide :D

Comment: There are a number of exceptions.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117366/176249

Comment: @CodeWarrior thanks, didn't know that correct answers don't count that's why I was able to get more than 200

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When missing 15 points that is often some other question where the OP changed his mind and selected another answer.

As you then no longer have any connection to that question, it will not show up on your a Reputation pane.

Comment: as of this moment, my answer is still marked as the right answer, and there was never another answer, unless this has happened on a different question while I was sleeping my answer was chosen and my answer was de-accepted on a different question, what are the odds?!

Comment: Guess what .. it's exactly what happened.. I'll select your answer as soon as the system let me